# Accessing Canvas and Button components in a scene

Tags: c#, unity

I have a scene with the following hierarchy:

[image]

This is game scene and the game manager is a singleton with the following variable fields:

```
// canvas
public Canvas PauseCanvas;
public Canvas MainMenuCanvas;
```

Before implementing singleton, I assigned them from the inspector. Now that the game manager is singleton, I need to assign them through script on level load. I can see one solution to this situation:

- Getting all canvas components through `GetComponents<Canvas>()` and then iterating and checking their `name` fields to assign them accordingly or maybe using LINQ.

**What I want to ask is**: Is there a name-based search method just like finding game objects with name `GameObject.Find("Name")` that is applicable for Components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such method but you can use this to find your elements : `yourCanvas = GameObject.Find("CanvasName").GetComponent<Canvas>();`

Comment: The main problem was choosing canvasses from multiple canvas components of a game object according to canvas' name. I used LINQ to solve it tho. Still, thanks for the answer.